# boost fusion: strange problem depending on number of elements on a vector

Tags: c++, boost, vector, boost-fusion

I am trying to use Boost::Fusion (Boost v1.42.0) in a personal project. I get an interesting error with this code:

```
#include "boost/fusion/include/sequence.hpp"
#include "boost/fusion/include/make_vector.hpp"
#include "boost/fusion/include/insert.hpp"
#include "boost/fusion/include/invoke_procedure.hpp"
#include "boost/fusion/include/make_vector.hpp"
#include <iostream>

class Class1
{ 
    public:
    typedef boost::fusion::vector<int,float,float,char,int,int> SequenceType;
    SequenceType s;
        Class1(SequenceType v):s(v){}
};

class Class2
{
    public:
    Class2(){}
    void met(int a,float b ,float c ,char d ,int e,int f)
    {
        std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << " " << d << " " << e << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argn, char**)
{
Class2 p;
Class1 t(boost::fusion::make_vector(9,7.66f,8.99f,'s',7,6));
boost::fusion::begin(t.s); //OK
boost::fusion::insert(t.s, boost::fusion::begin(t.s), &p); //OK
boost::fusion::invoke_procedure(&Class2::met,boost::fusion::insert(t.s, boost::fusion::begin(t.s), &p)); //FAILS
}
```

It fails to compile (gcc 4.4.1):

```
In file included from /home/thechaos/Escriptori/of_preRelease_v0061_linux_FAT/addons/ofxTableGestures/ext/boost/fusion/include/invoke_procedur
e.hpp:10,
                 from problema concepte.cpp:11:
/home/thechaos/Escriptori/of_preRelease_v0061_linux_FAT/addons/ofxTableGestures/ext/boost/fusion/functional/invocation/invoke_procedure.hpp: I
n function ‘void boost::fusion::invoke_procedure(Function, const Sequence&) [with Function = void (Class2::*)(int, float, float, char, int, in
t), Sequence = boost::fusion::joint_view<boost::fusion::joint_view<boost::fusion::iterator_range<boost::fusion::vector_iterator<const boost::f
usion::vector<int, float, float, char, int, int, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_>, 0>, 
boost::fusion::vector_iterator<boost::fusion::vector<int, float, float, char, int, int, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fus
ion::void_, boost::fusion::void_>, 0> >, const boost::fusion::single_view<Class2*> >, boost::fusion::iterator_range<boost::fusion::vector_iter
ator<boost::fusion::vector<int, float, float, char, int, int, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion:
:void_>, 0>, boost::fusion::vector_iterator<const boost::fusion::vector<int, float, float, char, int, int, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion
::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_>, 6> > >]’:
problema concepte.cpp:39:   instantiated from here
/home/thechaos/Escriptori/of_preRelease_v0061_linux_FAT/addons/ofxTableGestures/ext/boost/fusion/functional/invocation/invoke_procedure.hpp:88
: error: incomplete type ‘boost::fusion::detail::invoke_procedure_impl<void (Class2::*)(int, float, float, char, int, int), const boost::fusio
n::joint_view<boost::fusion::joint_view<boost::fusion::iterator_range<boost::fusion::vector_iterator<const boost::fusion::vector<int, float, f
loat, char, int, int, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_>, 0>, boost::fusion::vector_itera
tor<boost::fusion::vector<int, float, float, char, int, int, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::
void_>, 0> >, const boost::fusion::single_view<Class2*> >, boost::fusion::iterator_range<boost::fusion::vector_iterator<boost::fusion::vector<
int, float, float, char, int, int, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_>, 0>, boost::fusion:
:vector_iterator<const boost::fusion::vector<int, float, float, char, int, int, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::voi
d_, boost::fusion::void_>, 6> > >, 7, true, false>’ used in nested name specifier
```

However, if I change the number of arguments in the vectors and the method from 6 to 5 from `int,float,float,char,int,int` to `int,float,float,char,int`,I can compile it without problems.

I suspected about the maximum number of arguments being a limitation, but I tried to change it through defining `FUSION_MAX_VECTOR_SIZE` without success.

I am unable to see what am I doing wrong. Can you reproduce this? Can it be a boost bug (i doubt it but is not impossible)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes indeed, you need to change some iteration limits. You're just changing the wrong one. :)

What you need to define is `BOOST_FUSION_INVOKE_PROCEDURE_MAX_ARITY`; by default, it is 6. You obviously need 7 (but might as well bump it to 10):

```
#define BOOST_FUSION_INVOKE_PROCEDURE_MAX_ARITY 10

#include "boost/fusion/include/sequence.hpp"
#include "boost/fusion/include/make_vector.hpp"
#include "boost/fusion/include/insert.hpp"
#include "boost/fusion/include/invoke_procedure.hpp"
#include "boost/fusion/include/make_vector.hpp"
#include <iostream>
.
.
.
```

There are [three total](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/functional/invocation/limits.html) within the invocation domain.

Whenever you're looking for the limit of something, search for "Limits" on the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/index.html). Choose the one relevant to what you're doing. From there, it tells you the defaults and what the options are.

---

Just concerning the code itself, I should point out there is a [`push_front`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/algorithm/transformation/functions.html) function:

```
#include "boost/fusion/include/push_front.hpp"

// ...

boost::fusion::invoke_procedure(&Class2::met,
                                boost::fusion::push_front(t.s, &p));
```

So you don't need to do the more verbose insert-at-begin.

Comment: Oh thanks! I've been struggling 3 days with this error! That worked flawlessly.

Comment: I had a similar problem that required BOOST_FUSION_INVOKE_MAX_ARITY to be set instead. I'm not sure if it's a different define, or that the define name changed between versions.